# Module '"@uppy/core"' has no exported member 'debugLogger'

Tags: javascript, uppy

I'm trying to start up a new project in vanilla typescript with uppy but I keep getting an import error:

> Module '"@uppy/core"' has no exported member 'debugLogger'. Did you mean to use 'import debugLogger from "@uppy/core"' instead?

I'm following the docs and example sandboxes.

```
{
  "name": "vanilla-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "JavaScript and TypeScript example starter project",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html --open",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.6.1",
    "@uppy/core": "^3.8.0",
    "@uppy/drag-drop": "^3.0.3",
    "@uppy/status-bar": "^3.2.5",
    "@uppy/xhr-upload": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.8"
  },
  "keywords": ["typescript", "javascript"]
}
```

```js
import "./styles.css";

import Uppy, { debugLogger } from "@uppy/core";

console.log({ debugLogger });
```

[Here's a test sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/7y85my?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5fg0j00063b6j63xftuvd%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5fg0j00023b6j1iud5t1z%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5fg0j00033b6j9ksf02x2%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5fg0j00053b6jdnyrl4c8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqb5fg0j00023b6j1iud5t1z%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5fg0i00013b6jakgt16yz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5fg0j00023b6j1iud5t1z%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqb5fg0i00013b6jakgt16yz%2522%257D%252C%2522clqb5fg0j00053b6jdnyrl4c8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5fg0j00053b6jdnyrl4c8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqb5iqyv006u3b6j432ak3i8%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A1234%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5iqyv006u3b6j432ak3i8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clqb5fg0j00033b6j9ksf02x2%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5fg0j00033b6j9ksf02x2%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqb5imwc004q3b6j29bnbtns%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb5imwc004q3b6j29bnbtns%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) that errors and won't start up. What am I doing wrong here?